# NetBeans : How to connect two components , so that they perform the same action?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I have created a JMenuItem and a JButton in a JForm.
Is there an easy way to connect them so that they perform the same action, using Netbeans IDE?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `javax.swing.Action` to implement the logic (e.g. by extending `javax.swing.AbstractAction`) and then assign the action to the menu item *and* the button. Both have a constructor that takes an Action as the parameter.

Enabling/Disable the action will then also enable/disable the button and the menu item.

See the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/index.html)'s chapter about using actions for more details

Answer (score 1):

They both implement ItemSelectable. So you can try to create a controller which implements  ItemListener, implement its itemStateChanged() and add this listener to both the JMenuItem and the JButton (with addItemListener()).